# Server-Side Word Automation DocX.dll

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, server-side, docx

I would like to know how reliable is DocX.dll for server-side Word automation?

I have used Interop.Word and failed to have it work on the SQL Server. So, I am considering DocX.dll for the document manipulation.

Does anyone have idea how to setup (add reference) the .dll on server-side without Visual Studio?

I have copied the .dll files to bin Folder but it doesn't seem to be working. Button Click event is not responding, no error no exception.

```
<asp:Button ID="newDocument" runat="server" text="New Offer"
            OnClick="newDocument_Click"/>
```

Here is the OnClick Method:

```
protected void genDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DocX document = DocX.Load(@"g:\\OfferDocuments\\MainDocument.docx"); 

    if (!ReguTechProp.Checked) 
    { 
        // If checkbox not checked, remove the table 
        document.Tables[10].Remove(); 
    } 

    document.ReplaceText("Name", "Ayesha", false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    document.SaveAs(@"C:\\OfferDocument.docx"); 
}
```

It is working on my localhost, document is manipulated and saved. But not on server.

I have copied the DocX.dll in bin Folder of the project, on server. I have added reference to the .dll on my localhost through Visual Studio. Does that make any difference?

Also, I have the same code on Server. But when I click the Button, nothing happens. It doesn't show any error or any exception. And button/window doesn't even freeze.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to this DocX (https://docx.codeplex.com/) I have used it in a production environment for several years. It works well as long as you stick to simple document formats.

Comment: Yes. It works very well. But my question is, that nstead of saving the document on Drive, how can we diretly save it to Database. Like through Memorystream?
document.SaveAs(@"C:\\OfferDocument.docx"); 

I dont want this statement. I want to save the OfferDocument.docx to Database with Insert query and Add Parameter.